# Sending jwt to the client in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

First, let me give you an overview of my app, it is fairly simple.

The basic idea is that a user enters his accountname and password into an html form on the /Login page like:

```
<form action="/Login" method="post" target="_blank">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="username"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This works as expected, it makes a post request to /Login transferring username and password.
When the data gets to the server, the server checks if the username and password are valid, if they are a new JSON web token will be created. I use the npm library "bcrypt" for the verification of the account and "jsonwebtoken" for the creation of the token. This looks like this:

```
const accessToken = jwt.sign(user, process.env.JSON_TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: "10m" })
```

where the user is just an object, with an id key and a value whatever the name of the account is. If the username was admin it would look like this:

```
const user = { id: "admin" }
```

So now I want to deliver this token to the client and I do not know exactly how. I have tried:

```
res.json({ accessToken })
```

But all this does is displaying the JSON on the screen. I have also tried a regular res.send() but it won't deliver the token correctly to the user. I want a webtoken authentication so I can use protected routes in my project. If I want to visit a protected route, I get an error, that there is no authentication header, which probably means that the browser didn't receive the token correctly. The route protection is just basic middleware:

```
const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"]  //if console logged authHeader is undefined
const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(" ")[1]
jwt.verify(token, process.env.JSON_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
        //Some error handling
        next()
})
```

Next, I tried using Postman, where I made a POST request to /Login and got my token in the body of the response back. I pasted the token manually in a Bearer Authorization header and made a GET request to a protected route, which worked.

So how can I send the webtoken correctly to the client?

Comment: yes, your using a standard post form and responding with JSON, you should add more logic and respond differently for xhr.. besides you would need set the token into a cookie, preferably with `secure: true, signed: true` which you can then cascade down from `req.header`, else look in `req.signedCookies` for the token when making your verify/protected route middleware. **Dont do what others have suggested and store in localstorage** is not secure from XSS, use secure signed cookies over HTTPS or is not secure, no reason clientside needs to decode or even read the auth token. use a `/me` endpoint

Answer (score 0):

When you login with POST request it always send token in response so use some function to store that response in localStorage or sessionStorage or after successfully login you could send other request for getting a token from express server.

Answer (score 0):

when user signs in you create json web token. You have a login controller.

```
  const postLogin=(req,res)=>{
     // you read the req.body, get username,email, password etc
     // then you use email to see if user exists in db
    // if user exists, then you verify the password
    // if everything works so far you create the token
    //  token is kinda locked version of your inputs 
    // when you send it to server, only that server unlocks it with secret-key
    let token;
      try {
        token = jwt.sign({ _id: this._id, email: this.email }, "this-is-secret", {
          expiresIn: "1h",
        });
      } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(e.message);
      }
    res
        .status(200)
        .header("x-auth-token", token)
        .json({ token, userId: existingUser._id.toString() });
  }
```

x-auth=Extended authorization